# Strange order of results when adding joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a commenting system on my website but having issues with ordering the comments correctly. This is a screenshot of what I had before it went wrong:

[image]

And this is the query before it went wrong:

```
SELECT
    com.comment_id,
    com.parent_id,
    com.is_reply,
    com.user_id,
    com.comment,
    com.posted,
    usr.username
FROM
    blog_comments AS com
LEFT JOIN
    users AS usr ON com.user_id = usr.user_id
WHERE
    com.article_id = :article_id AND com.moderated = 1 AND com.status = 1
ORDER BY
    com.parent_id DESC;
```

I now want to include each comment's votes from my `blog_comment_votes` table, using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, and came up with this query, which works, but screws with the order of results:

```
SELECT
    com.comment_id,
    com.parent_id,
    com.is_reply,
    com.user_id,
    com.comment,
    com.posted,
    usr.username,
    IFNULL(c.cnt,0) votes
FROM
    blog_comments AS com
LEFT JOIN
    users AS usr ON com.user_id = usr.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT comment_id, COUNT(vote_id) as cnt
    FROM blog_comment_votes
    GROUP BY comment_id) c
    ON com.comment_id = c.comment_id
WHERE
    com.article_id = :article_id AND com.moderated = 1 AND com.status = 1
ORDER BY
    com.parent_id DESC;
```

I now get this order, which is bizarre:

[image]

I tried adding a GROUP BY clause on `com.comment_id` but that failed too. I can't understand how adding a simple join can alter the order of results! Can anybody help back on the correct path?

**EXAMPLE TABLE DATA AND EXPECTED RESULTS**

These are my relevant tables with example data:

[users]

```
user_id | username
--------|-----------------
1       | PaparazzoKid
```

[blog_comments]

```
comment_id | parent_id | is_reply | article_id | user_id |  comment      
-----------|-----------|----------|------------|---------|---------------------------
1          | 1         |          | 1          | 1       |  First comment
2          | 2         | 1        | 1          | 20      |  Reply to first comment
3          | 3         |          | 1          | 391     |  Second comment
```

[blog_comment_votes]

```
vote_id | comment_id | article_id | user_id
--------|------------|------------|--------------
1       | 2          | 1          | 233
2       | 2          | 1          | 122
```

So the order should be

```
First comment
    Reply to first comment    +2
Second Comment
```

Comment: K, first thing to note is that you shouldn't do this that way. You have to make article, comment and vote with their own id's respectively. Then hook tables to their respective tables by hooking their id's something like ( vote_id -> comment_id, comment_id -> article_id ). Now you would have something like, ( table for article ( article_id, article_text), comment ( comment_id, comment_text, article_id ) and vote ( vote_id, vote_rate, comment_id ). Mapping is as following OneToMany( article->comments, comment->votes) Hope it's now more clear to you.

Comment: @Takarakaka: Thank you for your time but unfortunately I don't understand that at all. I wish I did :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say without looking at your query results, but my guess is that it's because you are only ordering by parent id and not saying how to order when two records have the same parent id.  Try changing your query to look like this:

```
SELECT
    com.comment_id,
    com.parent_id,
    com.is_reply,
    com.user_id,
    com.comment,
    com.posted,
    usr.username,
    COUNT(c.votes) votes
FROM
    blog_comments AS com
LEFT JOIN
    users AS usr ON com.user_id = usr.user_id
LEFT JOIN 
    blog_comment_votes c ON com.comment_id = c.comment_id
WHERE
    com.article_id = :article_id AND com.moderated = 1 AND com.status = 1
GROUP BY 
    com.comment_id,
    com.parent_id,
    com.is_reply,
    com.user_id,
    com.comment,
    com.posted,
    usr.username
ORDER BY
    com.parent_id DESC, com.comment_id;
```